# Solid of revolution Finding the volume

Tags: integration

I'm student of 1-st term in university (SPB ITMO) and my teacher asked me to to complete one task. I have several equations: $$(x-4)y^2=x(x-3),\ x=0,\ y>0,$$ and I have to find a volume of solid of revolution around $x$-axis. The problem is that I don't understand what area on my graph of curve to take to integrate:   [wolframalpha-link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28x-4%29y%5E2=x%28x-3%29,y%3E0)

Answer (score 1):

I think what is meant is the volume of the solid of revolution around the $x$-axis of:
$$y(x) = \sqrt{\frac{x(x-3)}{x-4}}$$
Where $x$ is bounded between $x=0$ and $x=3$. Otherwise, if you allow the region $x>4$ as well, the volume will be infinite. The volume is given by:
$$V=\pi \int_0^3 y(x)^2 dx = \pi \int_0^3 \frac{x(x-3)}{x-4}dx$$
And can be evaluated easily by transforming $x \to t+4$:
$$V=\pi \int_{-4}^{-1} \frac{(1 + t) (4 + t)}{t}dt=
\pi \int_{-4}^{-1} 5+t+\frac{4}{t}dt = (7.5-4\log(4))\pi$$

Comment: Hmm, the volume is the integral of $\pi y^2$, so I don't see how elliptic integral arises.

Comment: @user1551 - my bad, fixed.